# How to use a specific PHP code (getDoctrine) to echo a combobox? I tried and the result is really not as expected

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to generate a combo box with values of my database in it.

To do so I decided to put a simple php code inside my .html.twig

Here is the code

```
<?php
            $villes = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('ProjetEsamuzeDiorBundle:Villes')
            ->findAll();

            echo "<select name='ville'>";

            for ($i=0;$i<count($villes)-1;$i++)
            {
                echo "<option value='".$villes[$i]->getId()."'>".$villes[$i]->getNom()."</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";
        ?>
```

The output of this is

```
getDoctrine() ->getRepository('ProjetEsamuzeDiorBundle:Villes') ->findAll(); echo ""; for ($i=0;i".$villes[i]->getNom().""; } echo ""; ?>
```

Keep in mind this is directly on the page, as if there was an echo just before, but there isn't. I thought maybe it's the $this, but replacing it with $villes gave the same result

Also I don't see the for what I see is exactly this

```
getDoctrine() ->getRepository('ProjetEsamuzeDiorBundle:Villes') ->findAll(); echo "(combobox is empty here)"; ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use PHP in twig templates. Twig is parsed and converted to PHP but no PHP code is interpreted. You have to use twig syntax.

Furthermore, you really shouldn't put logic into templates. Twig is doing great job preventing you from doing that. Database query should go to the controller.

Comment: Ohhhh that might explain it, so how should I get to the point I want to go? I'm still kinda new to Symfony AND php so I need some directions here

Comment: I used this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers to do what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be $villes[$i] instead of $villes[i] ?

Comment: Good catch, I changed it everywhere needed but still gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [entity form type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) for this task.